# How do I make a contained assembly use its own version of a third party assembly to what its parent uses

Tags: c#

I have read the below and heaps of posts on SO:

- https://devnet.kentico.com/articles/referencing-multiple-versions-of-the-same-assembly-in-a-single-application
- https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.assemblyresolve(v=vs.110).aspx
- https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/efs781xb(v=vs.110).aspx

but I cannot seem to achieve (without resorting to a GAC solution) what I need which is as follows:

**ThirdPartyLibrary.dll**

Installed via NuGet and has an AutoMapper dependency of AutoMapper >= 6.2.2 however ***ONLY WORKS*** with AutoMapper = 6.2.2 (Even though the dependency does not specify that)

**MyClassLibrary.dll**

This is something I have in production. Has a reference to AutoMapper 8.x and has a dependency of AutoMapper >= 8.0.0. Also needs a reference to **ThirdPartyLibrary.dll**

So all seems OK until MyClassLibrary actually makes a call to ThirdPartyLibrary.SomeMethod() which then fails because ThirdPartyLibrary is now using AutoMapper 8.x and throws an exception.

So my question is:

Without downgrading from AutoMapper 8.x how can I make ThirdParty use 6.2.2 of AutoMapper and MyClassLibrary carry on using 8.x?

I am happy to do this with either some app.config or AssemblyResolve. If I have to use AssemblyResolve it would be nice if I could hook up the event in MyClassLibrary otherwise I would have to revisit all the applications depending on MyClassLibrary.

Comment: I think [BindingRedirect](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/configure-apps/redirect-assembly-versions) will be helpful for you.

Comment: @vikscool As I understand it BindingRedirect is global for ALL references to a particular assembly. Not selective as in my case.